# Second event [onClick] does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I got 2 events [mousedown, click] on oen element, but second event works just, when I click next to the image [It is inside element] ... I have no words :)

Here is a code: codepen.io/Ivanowski/pen/JXeRpp

```js
$('.ripple').on('mousedown', function(event){
  // Check if shadow exists
  if( $(this).find('.shadow').length == 0 )
    $(this).append('<span class="shadow"></span>');

  var shadow = $(this).find('.shadow');
  // Remove animation if it exists
  shadow.removeClass('animation');

  // Set shadow size
  if( !shadow.width() && !shadow.height() )
  {
    var size = Math.max($(this).outerWidth(), $(this).outerHeight());

    shadow.css({
      width: size,
      height: size
    });
  }

  // Set shadow left, top
  var x = Math.round( event.clientX - this.getBoundingClientRect().left ) - ( shadow.width() / 2 );
  var y = Math.round( event.clientY - this.getBoundingClientRect().top ) - ( shadow.height() / 2 );


  shadow.css({
    left: x+'px',
    top: y+'px'
  });

  // Start animation
  shadow.addClass('animation');
});

/*
 * It does not work
*/
$('#switcher').on('click', function(){
  console.log('aaa');
});
```

```css
html
  height: 100%
body
  height: 100%
  background: #183145
  display: flex
  align-items: center
  justify-content: center
  
.swicher
  padding: 9px 5px
  cursor: pointer
  
.ripple
  overflow: hidden
  position: relative
  .shadow
    background: #fff
    border-radius: 100%
    position: absolute
    transform: scale(0)
    &.animation
      animation: ripple 0.6s linear
@keyframes ripple
  100%
    opacity: 0
    transform: scale(2.5)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="switcher" class="swicher ripple">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Ed2ShTk.png" alt="" />
  </a>
</span>
```

Try to press an image - event won't work.
Fast twice press on an image will work.

Why Does it happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: You should copy any relevant code into your question. Should your external links go down this question won't be of any use to others in the future.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

MouseClick event is emmiting, when your mouse button returns to the up state after it was down.
So technically when both up and down events are emitting on the same element, it emits the mouseClick.
Your animation scales the element with class shadow, so it overflows the image.
Mouse down emits on the image, but mouse up emits on the shadow element, because it overflows.

Try not to rise up mouse button immedeatly, wait the animation's end. And you will see that click event also emmited.

As a solution, you can add z-index: -1 to the shadow class. It will draw the element under the image, so events will work ok.

Comment: lol why someone downvoted it? Can u tell me, how i can fix it?

Comment: Yea, but when i add background to the element with ripple effect, it won't work. Can u tell me why it works, when I press twice on a element? [Without z-index]

Comment: The events emits in the following order. The first click: mouseDown emits on the swicher, mouseUp emits on the overflowed shadow; The second click: mouseDown emits on the overflowed shadow. Animation end. mouseUp emits on the switcher. up/down events pair registerd at the same element, mouseClick is emited.